# iOS Stack Overflow app thinks I'm not a member when I'm logged in and I attempt to upvote an answer

Tags: bug, ios-app

I'm logged in, I can read messages and see my profile. But when I try to upvote an answer an alert pops up asking:

> Add to your sites? You're not a member of Stack Overflow yet. Would you like to join?
>
> <kbd>Cancel</kbd><kbd>Join Site</kbd>

If I tap "Join Site" nothing appears to happen. I can run this through Charles proxy to see the errors if this is not a known issue.

[image: "Add to your sites? Your'e not yet a member of Stack Overflow yet. Would you like to join?"]

Comment: Does the behavior persist across questions and other answers?

Comment: @TylerH yep, all questions and answered showed the same alert. I just tried logging out and back in and that seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: The only difference between using an app and visiting the page directly is that an app is buggy and restricted. If it wasn't buggy and restricted, you may as well just visit the page directly. So this makes perfect sense.

Comment: I got the same issue

Answer (score 5):

Logging out and back in seems to have fixed the issue.

Should I close this question or keep it open until someone can look into why it happened?

Comment: Keep it, it's a bug.

Comment: Still occurring on iOS 12.1.4. I didn't need to sign out and sign back in though. I simply had to relaunch the app.