# iOS keeps forgetting that I already joined Meta

Tags: bug, ios-app

I'm using the Stack Exchange iOS App version 1.6.6.2 on my iPhone 6 with iOS version 12.4.3. Since a few days when I try to vote on a post on MSO I get the following message:

> You're not a member of Meta Stack Overflow yet. Would you like to join?

When I select to join I can vote. But after some period of inactivity the problem occurs again. I already found [this similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351246/3959259) and tried to log off and log on again but to no avail.

Other sites are not affected.

Comment: This happens to me on all child metas now.

Comment: The only meta not affected is [meta.se]. All other metas have this bug now. Appeared recently.

Comment: I keep forgetting I joined Meta too. I try not to think about it...

Comment: @Machavity YMMD :-)

Comment: While you’re in good cheer from Machavity’s comment, I have some bad news for you: the iOS and Android mobile apps for Stack Exchange are no longer maintained, and haven’t been in well over a year. I believe they have also been removed from the app stores. The intended replacement is the responsive view of the website, which I use all the time and I believe works pretty well for typical usage. There is also an older view of the site designed specifically for mobile devices. Use a link on the page footer to toggle between them.

Comment: @CodyGray Thank you for the info. So I assume that for now, the older view of the website works best, but in the future the responsive view will be recommended. Is this correct? Which browser(s) do you recommend for the mobile.use of SE sites, in particular on the iOS/iPhone? Do you prefer this to be a meta.se question?

Comment: @Timur The responsive mode works well. I use it exclusively on mobile. The mobile version is lacking moderation tools that I need, and I don’t like how it presents information in a different way than I’m used to from the desktop site. I use Safari on iOS. I’m at least one if not two iOS versions behind.